# How to exclude UI component from SonarQube Coverage but include in Code inspection?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Is there a way to make some settings so SonarQube will inspect all files but in Coverage, it excludes UI components made in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at ["Ignore Code Coverage"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-5) in SonarQube documentation.